# Deserialize complex JSON result

Tags: c#, json

I am automating an API. I would like to deserialize the `JSON` response I get but I can't figure out how to do it. This is the `JSON` I get as response:

```
{
  "class": [
    "Paged-Collection",
    "Products"
  ],

  "properties": {
    "defaultPageSize": 10,
    "skip": null,
    "top": 10,
    "totalRows": 2
  },

  "entities": [
    {
      "class": [
        "Product"
      ],
      "rel": [],
      "properties": {
        "Supplier": "Supplier1",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "ProductCode": "SomeCode1",
        "price": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "class": [
        "Product"
      ],
      "rel": [],
      "properties": {
        "Supplier": "Supplier2",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "ProductCode": "SomeCode2",
        "price": 73
      }
    },
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": [
        "self"
      ],
      "href": "http://localhost...",
      "method": "GET",
      "title": null,
      "type": null
    }
  ]
}
```

from what I've seen in other examples the deserialization boils down to figuring out the exact data strucutre (Not sure though if this what it is) however I made several attempts (not just rushing to SO for answer), so this is my last try:

The structure as I see it:

```
public class Data
{
    List<string> @class { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, MetaData> properties { get; set; }
    List<entities> entities { get; set; }
    List<LinkFeed> links { get; set; }
}
public class MetaData
{
    public int defaultPageSize { get; set; }
    public string skip { get; set; }
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int totalRows { get; set; }
}
public class entities
{
    public List<string> @class { get; set; }
    public List<string> rel { get; set; }
    public properties property { get; set; }
}

public class properties
{
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class LinkFeed
{
    public List<string> rel { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual deserialization using `Newtonsoft.Json` :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(data);
```

And everything is `Null`..

Actually the data that I'm really interested in is that under `"entities"` but I don't know if extracting only that will be actually easier or more difficult.

Comment: what are you getting as response? a json string, a json file or a json object?

Comment: Object but @CodingYoshi alreday figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your structure:

```
public class Rootobject {
   public string[] _class { get; set; }
   public Properties properties { get; set; }
   public Entity[] entities { get; set; }
   public Link[] links { get; set; }
}

public class Properties {
   public int defaultPageSize { get; set; }
   public object skip { get; set; }
   public int top { get; set; }
   public int totalRows { get; set; }
}

public class Entity {
   public string[] _class { get; set; }
   public object[] rel { get; set; }
   public Properties1 properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties1 {
   public string Supplier { get; set; }
   public string Currency { get; set; }
   public string ProductCode { get; set; }
   public int price { get; set; }
}

public class Link {
   public string[] rel { get; set; }
   public string href { get; set; }
   public string method { get; set; }
   public object title { get; set; }
   public object type { get; set; }
}
```

So you will do this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);
```

I would rename the class `Properties` to another name because it will clash with the `Properties` class of the assembly. This will give you headaches so just to be safe call it something else.

Also if you do not like some of the property names in the above classes, I mean I do not like it because it does not follow .NET naming conventions, then you can do this:

```
public class Rootobject {
  [JsonProperty( "class" )]
  public string[] MyClass { get; set; }

  // ... other properties
}
```

Obviously calling it `MyClass` is just an example, so give it a name that reflects the business domain.

Comment: `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(data, Rootobject);`, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. most surely I'll change the names, `class` and `property` surely don't seem fine, but I was trying to keep it as close as possible to the original naming from the `JSON` but now that I have working prototype I can play around with it!